# What badges should I include on my website, if any?

Tags: resume

I have made an about me page that contains basic information (basically my best websites and a link to their respective githubs.

I was thinking of including a few badges, like this:

[image]

on the website. Should I include them, and if so what badges should I include?

Comment: Personally, I despise flair on websites/portfolios, and I just use my stackoverflow careers page as a cv to send over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the badges you should include are the ones that are most relative to you.  if your an android developer and I was potential client looking for an android development I am more likely to select you over someone similar because you have evidence that you can help the community using android. (That is going by the fact I understand Stack Exchanges sites) if I was someone who didn't understand the Stack Exchange site the pretty picture would be good enough.

p.s nice badges!

Answer (score 3):

**None**

No one cares about Stack badges except stack users. If your clients have never heard of Stack Exchange, as with most people, then the badges only serve to confuse and distract. They offer no added value.

In addition, having a "badge" doesn't make you automatically an authority on the subject. Badges only reflect your interaction on Stack sites, not your overall knowledge and expertise. It is entirely possible to be hugely knowledgeable on a subject but not have a SE rep which reflects your knowledge. Just as it's possible to have a good deal of SE rep, while still not actually being an expert on the topic. SE badges only matter on SE sites, clients really don't care about them.

Leave them all off.